# Use of かける (N5 question)

Tags: word-choice, words, て-form, jlpt, particle-で

An N5 vocabulary question I'm having trouble understanding:

> わたしの　となりの　（　　　）　を　かけた　ひとは　すずきさんです。
>
> １　くつ　　　２　かぎ　　　３　めがね　　　４　でんわ

The answer is 3: わたしの　となりの　（　**めがね**　）　を　かけた　ひとは　すずきさんです。

Which I construe as *The person beside me who wore glasses is Suzuki-san.*

However, what is stopping 4 from being a valid answer?

> わたしの　となりの　（　**でんわ**　）　を　かけた　ひとは　すずきさんです。

I interpret this to be *The person beside me who made a call is Suzuki-san.*

A Google search of phrases in this question doesn't bring up anything helpful for me. The book's explanation doesn't cut it too: 「となり**で**　電話を　かけ**ている**　ひとは～」は◯。 Why must **で** and **かけている** be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### かけた as Current State

This question is testing whether you understand how the seemingly past tense かけた can actually be describing the **current state** of a person. This kind of verb usage happens a lot with articles of clothing.

The correct translation is not “who **wore** glasses”, but rather:

> The person beside me who **is wearing** glasses is Suzuki-san.

めがねを**かけている**人 or めがねを**かけた**人 most often means the person who **has glasses on**, and not the person who is *in the process of putting on* glasses, nor the person who *has put on* glasses at some point. Similarly, 青いコートを着た人 usually just means *person in a blue coat*, not *person who **wore** a blue coat*.

### かけた as Past Action

In contrast, the かけた in でんわを**かけた**人 clearly has a past tense meaning, i.e. *person who **made** a phonecall*.

As you point out, the でんわ choice is not ungrammatical per se (even though the context may be harder to imagine). However, the big hint is choice #2, かぎ. This noun acts similarly to でんわ, in that かぎを**かけた**人 means *person who **locked** (a door)*. Since you cannot have multiple correct answers, these choices can be ruled out. Sadly, multiple choice questions often involve this type of sleuthing and mind-reading.

---

> Why must で and かけている be used?

The textbook probably wanted to say that, in order to describe the person's **current state** and not an action done by them in the past, it must be 電話をかけている人 (*person who is making a phonecall*). Changing the となり**の** to となり**で** is not necessary, although the meaning will be altered a bit:

- 私のとなり**の**でんわをかけている人 *[person beside me] who is making a call*
- 私のとなり**で**でんわをかけている人 *person who is [making a call beside me]*

Comment: I still interpret 私の隣の電話をかけた人 as ''The one next to me who made a call" like when explaining to a 3rd person who also saw him calling.

Comment: This has been most helpful; thanks! I have read about て　いる being used for state continuation for quick actions like wearing clothes or glasses. So is it right to say た fulfils this function too? http://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/japanese-verbs-state-continuation.html

Comment: @Derpius I agree, it is grammatical and totally makes sense in some situations, as is the case with choice #2.

Comment: @rhyaeris Yes, but only when used in a noun phrase (e.g. [something]を着た[somebody]). So you can say コートを着た背の高いのが私です to mean “The tall one wearing a coat is me”, but 私はコートを着た will mean “I wore a coat” and not “I'm wearing a coat”.

Answer (score 0):

I think No.3 is better because I guess わたしのとなりの　～のひと means the situation of the person.As you said 隣で電話をかけている人 is no problem because the action comes after で like 公園で電話をかける.

However I think it is difficult to judge the difference between the action and the situation.I think 私の隣で電話をかけた人、私の隣で眼鏡をかけた人(the action of sporting a pair of glasses) are no problem.