# The grammar of Xには我慢がならん

Tags: grammar, set-phrases

> おかしな服{ふく}を着{き}た連中{れんちゅう}**には我慢{がまん}がならん。**
>   He couldn't bear folk who wore strange clothes.

My translation comes from the obvious context, plus the fact that Jisho says of ならん "Cannot bear not to". But I can't understand how it works. Should I just learn に(は)我慢がならん as a set phrase, or can the parts be understood separately?

My thought was that ならん may be a contraction of ならない (which seemed like a good idea because に always pairs up with なる). But then I literally have: Xには我慢がならん = patience does not become X. Which makes no sense.

Could you show me some other example using ならん? Do they have to use 我慢?

Comment: https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E6%88%91%E6%85%A2%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ならん is colloquialism for ならぬ, which is a literary/older version of ならない. Practically, you should learn 我慢(が)ならない as a set phrase meaning "unbearable". We never say 我慢がなる. This ない is obviously a negation marker, but there are several fixed expressions where ない has been almost incorporated in a single adjective.

Other examples:

- 鼻持ちならない / 鼻持ちならぬ / 鼻持ちならん
- 聞き捨てならない / 聞き捨てならぬ / 聞き捨てならん
- やんごとない
- 不甲斐ない
- やむない

If you want to understand the なる part etymologically, this 成る【なる】 means something like "to do/accomplish" rather than "to become" (cf. [為せば成る](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%82%BA%E3%81%9B%E3%81%B0%E6%88%90%E3%82%8B)). ならぬ/ならん by itself can mean "that's impossible" or "don't do it".

And also note that this 着た is not "who wore" but "wearing". See: [Use of かける (N5 question)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29671/5010)

Comment: Maybe I should have said "he **can't** bear people who **wear**", but I felt that "he **couldn't** bear people who **wore**" was a more natural way to express the same thing in English. I wasn't suggesting that 着た had a past tense meaning here. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: @user3856370 Ah, my mistake, I did not notice the main verb was also in the past tense.

Comment: Should `やむない` be `やまない`?

Comment: @Mauro やむない is correct. It's a variant of [this](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%84%E3%82%80%E3%82%92%E5%BE%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84).